# child state should load a directive inside parent ui-view

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

i have this config:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('ShowTabForm', {
            url: '/ShowTabForm/:id/:title',
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/pages/ShowTabForm.html',
            controller: 'tabFormController'
        })
        .state('ShowTabForm.LoadTabForm', {
            url: '/LoadTabForm/:tabId',
            template: '<dynamic-form></dynamic-form>'
        });
```

ShowTabForm.html is like below:

```
<div ng-controller="tabFormController">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

and in my tabFormController i change state:

```
$state.go('ShowTabForm.LoadTabForm', { tabId: 727 });
```

problem is, it does not load directive inside parent ui-view. when i trace code the dynamic-form controller run twice.
highly appreciate to help me fix this :)

UPDATE:
I found the problem but i can not solve it. The [dynamicForm] directive load correctly but dynamicform.html(view) render before data fetch from $http service inside dynamicFormController.
Any idea...?

Comment: When using ui-router you don't need to add the `ng-controller="tabFormController"` attribute to you template.

Comment: i did what you said but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended, based on comments - **There [is working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYFZE6WU31iQOsICtJKa?p=preview)**

let's have two $http calls to data1.json, data2.json. And that is the service:

```
  .factory('dynamicformService', ["$http", function ($http) {
    var getForm = function (objectId) {

      return $http({ method: "GET", url: "data" + objectId + ".json" })
        .then(function (result) {
          return result.data;
        });
    }; 

    return {
        getForm: getForm
    };
}])
```

and these is the UI-Router state controller

```
  .controller('dynamicformController', ['$scope','$stateParams', 'dynamicformService', 
  function dynamicformController($scope, $stateParams, dynamicformService){
    dynamicformService
        .getForm($stateParams.tabId)
        .then(function (forms) {
          $scope.forms = forms; 
        });
  }])
```

And finally the dynamic-form template

```
<div ng-repeat="form in forms" >

<label for="{{form.Name}}">{{form.Name}}</label>
<input 
  type="{{form.type}}" 
  name="{{form.Name}}" ng-model="form.Name" />

</div>
```

And these links make it working

```
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/2/title1/LoadTabForm/1">
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/2/title2/LoadTabForm/2">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYFZE6WU31iQOsICtJKa?p=preview)
Original part

Your solution should be working. To support it, I created **[a working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCysSt6wRtreQ3XZ5PvN?p=preview).**

This is the directive dynamic-form, which I used:

```
 .directive('dynamicForm', function(){
    return {
      template: "This is the dynamic Form",
      controller: function(){console.log("inside of a form")},
    };
  })
```

These links are working and rendering it:

```
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/1/title1">
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/2/title2">
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/2/title1/LoadTabForm/1">
<a href="#/ShowTabForm/2/title2/LoadTabForm/2">
```

The snippet of the state definition (as in the question) is NOT changed:

```
.state('ShowTabForm', {
    url: '/ShowTabForm/:id/:title',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/pages/ShowTabForm.html',
    controller: 'tabFormController'
})
.state('ShowTabForm.LoadTabForm', {
    url: '/LoadTabForm/:tabId',
    template: '<dynamic-form></dynamic-form>'
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCysSt6wRtreQ3XZ5PvN?p=preview)

Comment: my dynamicFrom directive call a $http.get service and create a form. it does not work. when i trace my code the dynamicFormController run twice and i did not know why!!!

Comment: Take my plunker, adjusted and reproduce the error. I am ready to assist. That's currently the max I can do, would not you agree?

Comment: I made your plunker working. Extended the answer to express the details. Hope now you have the answer ;)

Comment: I found the problem but i can not solve it. The [dynamicForm] directive load correctly but dynamicform.html(view) render before data fetch from $http service inside dynamicFormController. Any idea...?

Comment: ng-repeat on top of $scope.forms will render it properly, once data willcome, even async. I should you. In my example there is realy $http call

Comment: I am so glad to see that ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 1):

When using ui-router you don't need to add the `ng-controller="tabFormController"` attribute to you template. Also, it appears as if the `ShowTabForm.LoadTabForm` is a child state of the `ShowTabForm`, so you will have to add the `parent: 'ShowTabForm'` to your child state. Like so:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('ShowTabForm', {
            url: '/ShowTabForm/:id/:title',
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/pages/ShowTabForm.html',
            controller: 'tabFormController'
        })
        .state('ShowTabForm.LoadTabForm', {
            parent: 'ShowTabForm',
            url: '/LoadTabForm/:tabId',
            template: '<dynamic-form></dynamic-form>'
        });
```